# Undefined: index keywords (CMS)

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I would like to make a CMS in PHP and MySQL, but I get the error Undefined: index keywords, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$post_title = $_POST['title'];
$post_date = date('d-m-y');
$post_author = $_POST['author'];
$post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$post_content = $_POST['content'];
$post_image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];


if($post_title=='' or  $post_keywords=='' or $post_content=='' or $post_author==''){

    echo "<script>alert('any of the field is empty')</script>";

    exit();


}

    else{

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "images/$post_image");

        $insert_query = "insert into posts (post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_content) values ('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author','$post_image', '$post_keywords', $post_content)";

        if (mysql_query($insert_query)) {

        echo "<center><h1>Post Published succesfully!</h1></center>";

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please show us your html form. Also that means that `$_POST['keywords']` isn't set!

Comment: Check if your form element for it holds a name attribute. If it doesn't, then there's the problem.

Comment: Sidenote: `'$post_keywords', $post_content` - `$post_content` stands to be a string; quote it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that the `$_POST` array actually has an element with the key `keywords` before accessing it:

```
$post_title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
$post_date = date('d-m-y');
$post_author = isset($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] : '';
$post_keywords = isset($_POST['keywords']) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
$post_content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';
$post_image = isset($_FILES['image']['name']) ? $_FILES['image']['name'] : '';
$image_tmp = isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] : '';
```

another way to write this would be ie:

```
if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
} else {
    $post_keywords = '';
}
```

If you are expecting to have keywords posted every time you should verify that the name of your input field matches exactly the key in the post array and that there are no typos.

- You should also make sure that your form's element holds a name attribute.

I.e.: `name="keywords"`

Comment: *"`if (isset($_POST['title'])`"* - It's not "title" that's undefined, it's "keywords". You also made a typo "titte". Plus a missing bracket. ^

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the concept is the same for either key but I get your point

Comment: Reload my comment, you missed something ;-)

Comment: Good eye! Thanks Fred

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition to verify if there are any POST data.

```
if ($_POST) {
   //do your staff here
} else {
   //redirect to the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in a simple way:

```
//Save images data in variable

echo $post_image = isset($_FILES['post_image']['name']) ?   
    $_FILES['post_image']['name'] : '';

echo $image_tmp = isset($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name']) ?   
    $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'] : '';

if ($post_title == '' OR $post_author == '') {
    echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the data')</script>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done this in a simple way:

```
//Images data save in Variables
echo $post_image = isset($_FILES['post_image']['name']) ? $_FILES['post_image']['name'] : '';
echo $image_tmp = isset($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'] : '';
if($post_title=='' OR $post_author==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the data')</script>";
    exit();
}
```